# removeEventlistener not working as expected with arrow function and parameter

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I've got a page which can hold multiple editable contents. I want to fire some kind of check event whenever the content is edited.

My code to achieve this looks like this:

```
// Find all editable elements.
let allEditableElements = document.querySelectorAll('[contenteditable="true"]');

for(let i = 0; i < allEditableElements.length; i++){

  //Remove eventListener to prevent duplicate events.
  allEditableElements[i].removeEventListener('input', (event) => {myClass.myEventMethod(event);}, false);

  // Add event.
  allEditableElements[i].addEventListener('input', (event) => {myClass.myEventMethod(event);}, false);
}
```

Everything works fine so far. But as I said users can edit the content, which includes adding new editable contents to the page itself. At that point the events will be set again, which is why I'm trying to remove the `event` beforehand.

**My question is why would the `removeEventListener` function not work as expected? And isn't there a way to name given events like so:**

```
// With eventNameGivenByUser an event could be removed just by its name.
addEventListener('eventTriggerName', 'eventNameGivenByUser', function(), [, options]);
```

---

Of course I did some research and found out that the code itself would work like this:

```
// Find all editable elements.

let allEditableElements = document.querySelectorAll('[contenteditable="true"]');

for(let i = 0; i < allEditableElements.length; i++){

  //Remove eventListener to prevent duplicate events.
  allEditableElements[i].removeEventListener('input', myClass.myEventMethod, false);

  // Add event.
  allEditableElements[i].addEventListener('input', myClass.myEventMethod, false);
}
```

However this is without passing parameters, which is mandatory in such a dynamic setup...

Hope someone will tell me that in 2017 there is a nice and decent way without using libraries.

---

**Edit 08.02.2017:**

Just for the curious ones:
The Solution is to not pass any parameter to the listener:

```
// as you can see there is no (event) and no arrow function either.
addEventListener('input', myClass.myEventMethod, false);
```

All there is to do now is to call prepare the method like this:

```
// The Parameter will be passed through anyway!
myEventMethod(event) {

      /**
      * Do stuff with event parameter.
      */

};
```

After that the listener can be removed like so:

```
removeEventListener('input', myClass.myEventMethod, false);
```

---

**Sidenote:**

I'm using electron and do not need cross browser support. It just has to be compatible with `Chromium: 56.0.2924.87`.

Regards, Megajin

Comment: The problem is obvious, but to offer a solution we need real world code. In particular this: _"However this is without passing parameters"_ The code in the question does not pass parameters. It goes without saying that a better approach would eliminate the problem altogether.

Comment: @zeroflagL of course I'm able to solve the problem with adding the listener to a newly created element instead of running through them all. I was just curious if there is a better way like `element.hasEvent()`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `removeEventListener` method takes at least two arguments: the event name and the listener function to remove.

In your first example:

```
  allEditableElements[i].removeEventListener('input', (event) => {myClass.myEventMethod(event);}, false);
```

you are defining a new function which wasn't previously attached as event listener, so it can not be removed.

I don't know what's wrong with your second attempt:

```
allEditableElements[i].removeEventListener('input', myClass.myEventMethod, false);
```

this one should work fine. However you could combine both approaches: wrap your class method in a function, and attach the wrapped version as an listener. You just need to have a reference to make it possible to remove later:

```
const inputListener = (event) => { myClass.myEventMethod(event); };
let allEditableElements = document.querySelectorAll('[contenteditable="true"]');


for(let i = 0; i < allEditableElements.length; i++){

  //Remove eventListener to prevent duplicate events.
  allEditableElements[i].removeEventListener('input', inputListener, false);

  // Add event.
  allEditableElements[i].addEventListener('input', inputListener, false);
}
```

**All that said I'd advise to just use event delegation**. Attach the listener on an element higher up in the DOM and don't worry about clearing and re-adding event listeners when new elements appear:

```
const handleContentEditable = e => {
    if( e.target.isContentEditable ){
        console.log( 'editing ', e.target );
    }
};

document.body.addEventListener('input', handleContentEditable );
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rd3y9gh9/1/

Comment: @Kaiido updated the check to `e.target.isContentEditable`, thanks.

Comment: Wow... thank you for your answer I've found a solution with your help. I do not need to pass the parameter `(event)` while declaring the listener... The parameter will be passed through anyway. And thanks for the event delegation advise, I will look at that too. +1 and accepted answer!

Answer (score 3):

This is because the arrow function in removeEventListener is creating a new function reference. removeEventListener requires a reference to the original method passed to addEventListener.

You will have to preserve a reference to the event method in your case OR you can recreate the input elements on the fly, this will remove all event listeners.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode

Clone Node does not copy event listeners so you could probably use that to clone the original element and replace it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I wasn't thinking about arrow functions +1 for that. However I've found a solution. I do not need to pass the `event` parameter to the listener function.