# JavaScript - removeEventListener not working consistently

Tags: javascript, events

I have a strange situation where previously added event listeners sometimes are successfully removed and sometimes they are not.

Let's start with a sample code:

```
    this.Start_Measuring_Slider_Drag = function(p_Event) {

        // Function invoked upon mousedown event..

        console.log("Start dragging...") ;

        var l_Scroll_Pane_ID  = this.Foreign_Mesh.Config.Element_ID + "_VerticalScroll_Inner_div" ;
        var l_Scroll_Pane_Obj = document.getElementById(l_Scroll_Pane_ID) ;

        l_Scroll_Pane_Obj.addEventListener("mouseup"    , event => this.Complete_Scroll         (event , l_Scroll_Pane_ID)) ;
        l_Scroll_Pane_Obj.addEventListener("mousemove"  , event => this.Mouse_Move_During_Scroll(event , l_Scroll_Pane_ID)) ;
        l_Scroll_Pane_Obj.addEventListener("mouseleave" , event => this.Cancel_Scroll           (event , l_Scroll_Pane_ID)) ;
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    this.Mouse_Move_During_Scroll = function (p_Event) {
        console.log("Mouse is moving ")
    }
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    this.Complete_Scroll = function (p_Event , p_Element_ID) {
        console.log("Completing scroll at y: " + (p_Event || window.event).pageY) ;
        
        this.Remove_Scrolling_Listeners (p_Element_ID) ;
    }
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    this.Cancel_Scroll = function(p_Event , p_Element_ID) {
        console.log("Need to cancel scroll at: " + (p_Event || window.event).pageY)

        this.Remove_Scrolling_Listeners (p_Element_ID) ;
    }
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    this.Remove_Scrolling_Listeners = function (p_Element_ID) {

        console.log("Removing listeners...")

        var l_Scroll_Pane_Obj = document.getElementById(p_Element_ID) ;

        l_Scroll_Pane_Obj.removeEventListener("mouseup"    , event => this.Complete_Scroll         (event , p_Element_ID)) ;
        l_Scroll_Pane_Obj.removeEventListener("mousemove"  , event => this.Mouse_Move_During_Scroll(event , p_Element_ID)) ;
        l_Scroll_Pane_Obj.removeEventListener("mouseleave" , event => this.Cancel_Scroll           (event , p_Element_ID)) ;
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

and here is the output within the console.

[image: Console output]

The output at the console shows (green arrows + (A)) that, after removing the listeners, there are no captured mouse movements (though I did move it quite a lot!!). The orange arrow (B) indicates that the mouse moved away from the div ("mouseout" event) which also invoked the function that removes the listeners ("`this.Remove_Scrolling_Listeners`"). Here, however, movements of the mouse are still being watched as shown by the red arrow (C).

Bottom line: The same mechanism is used to remove listeners but it sometimes work and sometimes does not.

### Update

Following Keith's suggestion, I changed the code as shown below:

```
    this.Start_Measuring_Slider_Drag = function(p_Event) {

        console.log("Start dragging...") ;

        var l_Scroll_Pane_ID  = this.Foreign_Mesh.Config.Element_ID + "_VerticalScroll_Inner_div" ;
        var l_Scroll_Pane_Obj = document.getElementById(l_Scroll_Pane_ID) ;

        this._mouseUp    = event => this.Complete_Scroll         (event) ;
        this._mouseMove  = event => this.Mouse_Move_During_Scroll(event) ;
        this._mouseLeave = event => this.Cancel_Scroll           (event) ;

        l_Scroll_Pane_Obj.addEventListener("mouseup"    , this.Complete_Scroll         (this._mouseUp    )) ;
        l_Scroll_Pane_Obj.addEventListener("mousemove"  , this.Mouse_Move_During_Scroll(this._mouseMove  )) ;
        l_Scroll_Pane_Obj.addEventListener("mouseleave" , this.Cancel_Scroll           (this._mouseLeave )) ;
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    this.Mouse_Move_During_Scroll = function (p_Event) {
     
        console.log("Mouse is moving ")
        // console.log("Mouse Y coordinate: " + (p_Event || window.event).pageY)
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    this.Complete_Scroll = function (p_Event) {

        console.log("Completing scroll at y: " + (p_Event || window.event).pageY) ;

        this.Remove_Scrolling_Listeners () ;
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    this.Cancel_Scroll = function(p_Event) {

        console.log("Need to cancel scroll at: " + (p_Event || window.event).pageY)

        this.Remove_Scrolling_Listeners () ;
    }
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    this.Remove_Scrolling_Listeners = function () {

        console.log("Removing listeners...")

        var l_Scroll_Pane_ID  = this.Foreign_Mesh.Config.Element_ID + "_VerticalScroll_Inner_div" ;
        var l_Scroll_Pane_Obj = document.getElementById(l_Scroll_Pane_ID) ;

        l_Scroll_Pane_Obj.removeEventListener("mouseup"    , this._mouseUp    ) ;
        l_Scroll_Pane_Obj.removeEventListener("mousemove"  , this._mouseMove  ) ;
        l_Scroll_Pane_Obj.removeEventListener("mouseleave" , this._mouseLeave ) ;
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

This does not work at all... Upon pressing the mouse button (i.e. mousedown), all the events appear to be fired at once as shown in the console:

```
Start dragging...
Completing scroll at y: undefined
Removing listeners...
Mouse is moving 
Need to cancel scroll at: undefined
Removing listeners...
```

This condition repeats whenever mousedown event takes place. Furthermore, when moving the mouse while the button is down (i.e. dragging), no indication is shown that the system is monitoring the mouse movements (nothing is written into the console since, normally, when the mouse moves it would display the same message with the number of repetitions, something like "`123 Mouse is moving`
").

### Update 2

I wrongly implemented Keith's suggested solution. Once fixed (to look as suggested), things work like a charm. See Keith's answer for details.

Comment: Duplicate of [removeEventlistener not working as expected with arrow function and parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42111404/removeeventlistener-not-working-as-expected-with-arrow-function-and-parameter)

Comment: Have you tried to add your listener on document for "mouseup" ? If the mouse is outside of your l_Scroll_Pane_obj when "up", event is not fired... document.addEventListener("mouseup",  this.Complete_Scroll) ;

Comment: Removing event listeners sounds like a code smell to me. Instead test in the eventListener if it should be active or not

Comment: Use named event handlers not anonymous event handlers. ex. `node.addEventListener("event", namedEventHandler);` `function namedEventHandler(e) {...}` `node.removeEventListener("event", namedEventHandler);` Also, it's pointless to use arrow functions and `this` keyword.

Comment: You have to keep a reference to the event you added to be able to remove, `event =>` is a new event handler in all cases.  IOW: `const event = () => {}; element.addEventListener(event); element.remveEventListener(event)` would work, but `element.addEventListener(event => {}); element.removeEventListner(event => {})` does not work, because each `event => {}` are not the same.

Comment: `sometimes are successfully`,  You will also find they are consistently unsuccessfully.  And is the reason you have those number's in the console getting larger & larger.

Comment: @zer00ne  `Also, it's pointless to use arrow functions and this keyword`  Well, it's kind of the whole point of arrow functions, to keep the current `this` context..  The OP isn't using `this` here to access the event target, but his own class.

Comment: Thank you @GuyIncognito for your comment, but my problem has nothing to do with arrows (buttons). The reference you mentioned is a substantially different situation.

Comment: Thank you @kopacabana. I agree with your comment but this is not my case. Please take a look to the listeners I'm using. If the mouse moves outside of a container div, the function `this.Cancel_Scroll` is invoked as shown in the console (`Need to cancel scroll...`).

Comment: ...what? Your event listeners are *arrow functions* (`event => ...`). The duplicate is exactly the same as your issue.

Comment: OOOPS :-) !!!! @GuyIncognito, I thought you meant something else.

Comment: Just worth pointing out here though, adding & removing events has nothing to do if the function is an arrow function or not,  in both cases you need to keep a reference to the actual event added.

Comment: @Keith, thank you for your input. I tried your suggestion (defining different variables for each listener) without success. Also, it is important to note that the listeners to `mouseup` and `mousemove` work as required. The only one that fails to produce what I want is the `mouseleave`. When such event takes place, the required function is indeed invoked BUT the removeListener for the `mousemove` does not appear to remove it at all. If you take a detail look at the console shown in my question you will see that.

Comment: @Keith, I re-examined things and am not sure I implemented your suggestion the way you meant. Could you take from the code shown in the question the pieces where I add the event listeners and the one where I (try to) remove them, patch it as you suggest and post it as an answer? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @FDavidov  I'll take a look, give us a tick.

Comment: @Keith  I didn't notice that OP code is a class...? If it is, then the example is incomplete. I noticed that the `eventListeners` in your answer do not use arrow functions as event handlers...

Comment: @zer00ne, as someone pointed out, the use of `this.` does suggest it is a class already. The whole class exceeds 1600 lines and hence I posted only the relevant piece of code.

Comment: @zer00ne  `this._mouseUp = event => this.Complete_Scro....` is an arrow function..

Comment: @Keith sure it's an arrow function but not an `eventListener`. At best it's an event property but we can never really say if it truly handles events since there's no definition of any of the methods.

Comment: @zer00ne  I've really no idea what your on about,  it gets used here -> `addEventListener("mouseup", this._mouseUp)`   `this._mouseUp` is an arrow function, that I'm assigning to `addEventListener`.   IOW: I'm assigning an arrow function to the mouseup event.

Comment: @Keith I see you're just binding method as an event handler but need to call it something else because the context of `this` is lost. Simple use of `.bind()` is less confusing. `this.methodName = this.methodName.bind(this);`. Sorry I can't follow incomplete code very well.

Comment: @zer00ne, as posted as a comment to Keith's solution, after correctly implementing things, the code behaves exactly as expected/needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your code is part of a class, with all the `this` logic.

As such the modifications I would suggest is keeping a track of the event handler your adding.

eg.

```
    this.Start_Measuring_Slider_Drag = function(p_Event) {

        // Function invoked upon mousedown event..

        console.log("Start dragging...") ;

        var l_Scroll_Pane_ID  = this.Foreign_Mesh.Config.Element_ID + "_VerticalScroll_Inner_div" ;
        var l_Scroll_Pane_Obj = document.getElementById(l_Scroll_Pane_ID) ;

        //keep a track of the events we will be adding.
        this._mouseUp = event => this.Complete_Scroll(event , l_Scroll_Pane_ID);
        this._mouseMove = event => this.Mouse_Move_During_Scroll(event , l_Scroll_Pane_ID);
        this._mouseLeave = event => this.Cancel_Scroll           (event , l_Scroll_Pane_ID);

        //now add the event listeners. 
        l_Scroll_Pane_Obj.addEventListener("mouseup", this._mouseUp) ;
        l_Scroll_Pane_Obj.addEventListener("mousemove", this._mouseMove) ;
        l_Scroll_Pane_Obj.addEventListener("mouseleave", this._mouseLeave ) ;
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    this.Mouse_Move_During_Scroll = function (p_Event) {
        console.log("Mouse is moving ")
    }
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    this.Complete_Scroll = function (p_Event , p_Element_ID) {
        console.log("Completing scroll at y: " + (p_Event || window.event).pageY) ;
        
        this.Remove_Scrolling_Listeners (p_Element_ID) ;
    }
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    this.Cancel_Scroll = function(p_Event , p_Element_ID) {
        console.log("Need to cancel scroll at: " + (p_Event || window.event).pageY)

        this.Remove_Scrolling_Listeners (p_Element_ID) ;
    }
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    this.Remove_Scrolling_Listeners = function (p_Element_ID) {

        console.log("Removing listeners...")

        var l_Scroll_Pane_Obj = document.getElementById(p_Element_ID) ;

        //use our stored events to remove
        l_Scroll_Pane_Obj.removeEventListener("mouseup", this._mouseUp) ;
        l_Scroll_Pane_Obj.removeEventListener("mousemove", this._mouseMove) ;
        l_Scroll_Pane_Obj.removeEventListener("mouseleave" , this._mouseLeave) ;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @Keith for your suggestion, but it does not work as expected. The original question was edited and now it shows the code reflecting the changes you suggested. Please take a look. Thanks.

Comment: @FDavidov  You don't seem to have copied code exactly the same as I posted. `addEventListener("mousemove", this._mouseMove) ;` <--- make sure you do this too.  You have this instead -> `addEventListener("mousemove"  , this.Mouse_Move_During_Scroll(this._mouseMove  )) ;`

Comment: Thank you Keith!!! Indeed I wrongly implemented your solution. After the fix it works like a charm!!!