# removeEventListener for transitionend not working

Tags: ecmascript-6, removeeventlistener, transitionend

I have two buttons on the screen. When one is clicked, both slide off the screen by adding css class - which in turn, adds a margin-left css property.

I also have a 'transitionend' eventListener which does some stuff once the transition is complete. My code is

```js
for (const btn of buttons) {

    btn.addEventListener('transitionend', function func(e)
    {
        if (e.propertyName !== 'margin-left') return;

        ... do some stuff ...

        btn.removeEventListener('transitionend', func, false);
    }, false);

    btn.classList.add('slide-out');
}
```

The `addEventListener` is working, and the `... do some stuff ...` is doing it's thang. But the eventListener is not being removed from either of the buttons.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you certain the `func` passed into `removeEventListener` has the same object-reference as the `function func` closure you're passing into `addEventListener`?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42111404/removeeventlistener-not-working-as-expected-with-arrow-function-and-parameter

Comment: The `func` function is declared as the second argument to the addEventListener. Does this give it a different object reference?

Comment: Possibly. Also, there's a bug in your code: you aren't handling the `transitioncancel` event which can happen as an alternative to `transitionend` (which means your code will leak event-handler references because `removeEventListener` would never be called). Also consider moving your `removeEventListener` call to the `finally` part of a `try` block for safety.

Comment: Moving the func outside of the addEventListener worked. Thanks for your help

Comment: I tried to recreate the error. I used an `alert('done');`  for `... do some stuff ...` The `btn.removeEventListener` worked. So I am suggesting your `... do some stuff ...` crashes before `btn.removeEventListener` is executed.